# Fast and elegant way to calculate fold change between several groups for many variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

Out of curiosity I have been playing with several ways to calculate fold changes and I am trying to find the fastest and the most elegant way to do that (hoping that would also be the same solution).

The kind of matrix I am interested in would look like this:

```
# Some data
nvars <- 10000
nsamples <- 500
sample_groups <- 5
MAT <- replicate(nvars, runif(n=nsamples))
```

And a grouping vector that look like this:

```
f <- rep_len(1:sample_groups, nsamples)
f <- LETTERS[f]
```

The output I would like in the end from the above input is a 10 x 10,000 matrix with one row for each combination of the levels in `f`.

To do this the first task is to calculate the mean for each group for all column.
I have come up with 4 possible methods to do that:

---

```
# Settings
aggr_FUN  <- mean
combi_FUN <- function(x,y) "/"(x,y) 

# helper function
pasteC <- function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=" - ")
```

```
#A1. Loop
system.time({
f_un <- unique(f)
temp1 <- matrix(NA,nrow = length(f_un),ncol=ncol(MAT))
rownames(temp1) <- f_un

for(i in 1:length(f_un)){
  temp1[i,] <- apply(MAT[f_un[i] == f,,drop=FALSE],2,aggr_FUN)
}
})


 user  system elapsed 
   0.41    0.00    0.41
```

```
#A2. aggregate
system.time({
temp2 <- aggregate(. ~ class, data = cbind.data.frame(class=f,MAT), aggr_FUN)
})


 user  system elapsed 
   7.76    0.05    7.81
```

```
#A3. reshape2
library(reshape2)
system.time({
temp3 <- recast(data.frame(class=f,MAT),class ~ variable,id.var="class",aggr_FUN)
})


  user  system elapsed 
   1.82    0.30    2.12
```

```
#A4. purrr
library(purrr)
system.time({
temp4 <- data.frame(class = f, MAT) %>%
  slice_rows("class") %>%
  by_slice(map, aggr_FUN)
})


   user  system elapsed 
   0.47    0.00    0.47
```

---

As you can see the loop is actually the fastest solution with the `purrr` package being only slightly slower. `recast` is 5 times slower and `aggregate` is a clear looser.
I also tried the dplyr package but that turned out to be very slow for some reason (https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1395).

`purrr` is both fast and elegant so for this part it is a pretty academic exercise looking for a better way.

At this point the output we have is:

```
> temp1[,1:6]
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
A 0.4804964 0.4779168 0.5292458 0.4401357 0.4728515 0.5009800
B 0.4819612 0.5260592 0.5291887 0.5095620 0.4840777 0.4792213
C 0.4661714 0.4886010 0.5006018 0.5061170 0.5058892 0.5432819
D 0.4566942 0.4519988 0.5334207 0.4912822 0.4542889 0.4898384
E 0.4967948 0.5630683 0.4941777 0.5239327 0.5045152 0.5227140
```

So if you are still reading here comes the more challenging part. We need to calculate the fold change between all combinations of the groups/rows.

I found two ways to do this:

```
#B1. by loop
combs <- t(combn(as.character(f_un),2))
combi_FUN_vec <- Vectorize(combi_FUN)

out <- matrix(NA,nrow = nrow(combs),ncol=ncol(temp1))
rownames(out) <- pasteC(combs[,1],combs[,2])
colnames(out) <- 1:ncol(temp1)

system.time({

for( i in 1:nrow(combs)){
  out[i,] <- combi_FUN_vec(    temp1[combs[i,1],]      ,         temp1[combs[i,2],]   )
}

})


  user  system elapsed 
   0.13    0.00    0.13
```

```
#B2. by apply
class_computed <- as.character(temp2[,1])
temp2 <- as.matrix(temp2[,-1])
combs <- t(combn(class_computed,2))
rownames(temp2) <- class_computed

combi_FUN_vec <- Vectorize(combi_FUN)

system.time({

out <- apply(temp2,2,function(x){
  v <- combi_FUN_vec(    x[combs[,1]]      ,        x[combs[,2]]    )
  names(v) <- pasteC(combs[,1],combs[,2])
  return(v)
})

})


   user  system elapsed 
   0.91    0.00    0.91
```

Not surprisingly the loop is a clear winner and the output is this:

```
> out[,1:5]
              1         2         3         4         5
A - B 1.2128952 1.0161608 0.9313115 0.9767619 1.0132362
A - C 1.0946079 1.0524154 0.9882857 0.9546686 0.9604382
A - D 1.1872958 0.9113349 0.9941437 0.8751611 0.9863873
A - E 1.1457396 0.9669100 0.9146375 0.8760513 1.0604971
B - C 0.9024753 1.0356780 1.0611763 0.9773810 0.9478918
B - D 0.9788940 0.8968413 1.0674664 0.8959820 0.9735018
B - E 0.9446320 0.9515325 0.9820962 0.8968933 1.0466435
C - D 1.0846768 0.8659461 1.0059275 0.9167172 1.0270179
C - E 1.0467123 0.9187532 0.9254788 0.9176496 1.1041804
D - E 0.9649993 1.0609821 0.9200254 1.0010171 1.0751326
```

Now here is what bugs me... These two last methods are extremely ugly.
Is there a better/cleaner/faster way? Preferably in `dplyr`/`purrr` style syntax? Perhaps without having to go through `combn` even?

Any hints are appreciated.

EDIT:

I manage to make a much more compact version in dplyr style:

```
f_un <- unique(f)
  combs <- t(combn(as.character(f_un),2))

  out3 <- data.frame(class = f, MAT) %>%  slice_rows("class") %>% by_slice(map, aggr_FUN) %>% 
          do(combi_FUN( slice(.,match(combs[,1], class))[,-1]  ,slice(.,match(combs[,2], class))[,-1]      )) %>% 
          as.data.frame(row.names = pasteC(combs[,1],combs[,2]))
```

Is there a way to simplify that and speed it up? It is 10x slower than the fastest above.

EDIT2:
Based on the suggestions so far the fastest and cleanest is the below function.

```
fold.change <- function(MAT,f,aggr_FUN=mean,combi_FUN=function(x,y) "/"(x,y)   ){

  # mean using purrr
  x <- data.frame(class = f, MAT) %>%  slice_rows("class") %>% by_slice(map, aggr_FUN)
  rownames <- as.character(as.data.frame(x[,1])[,1])
  x <- as.matrix(x[,-1])
  rownames(x) <- rownames

  # calculate changes between all rows
  i <- combn(unique(f), 2)
  ret <- combi_FUN(x[i[1,],] , x[i[2,],])
  rownames(ret) <- pasteC(i[1,], i[2,])

  # Put original colnames
  colnames(ret) <- colnames(MAT)

  return(ret)
}
```

Comment: Why are you renaming `mean` and `/` as `aggr_FUN` and `combi_FUN`? You are losing efficiency right there.

Comment: You could increase the speed of `aggregate` by avoiding the cbinding to a `data.frame` - `aggregate(MAT, list(f), FUN=mean)` , or use it's cousin `tapply` to speed up base functions `tapply(MAT, list(rep(f,ncol(MAT)), col(MAT)), FUN=mean)`

Comment: Failing to sleep I instead manage to make a much more compact version in dplyr style. See edit above. Is there a way to simplify that and speed it up? It is 10x slower than the fastest version above.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for the suggestion. It did speed aggregate up 6 fold. and tapply falls between the loop/purrr and recast.

Comment: @jeremycg I rename the functions to be able to build a wrapper that can pass any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix operations and subsetting are fast:

```
fold <- function(x, f, aggr_FUN = colMeans, combi_FUN = '/'){
  f <- as.factor(f)
  i <- split(1:nrow(x), f)
  x <- sapply(i, function(i){ aggr_FUN(x[i,])})
  x <- t(x)
  j <- combn(levels(f), 2)
  ret <- combi_FUN(x[j[1,],], x[j[2,],])
  rownames(ret) <- paste(j[1,], j[2,], sep = '-')
  ret
}

> system.time(ret <- fold(MAT, f))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.13    0.00    0.12 
> all.equal(ret, out, check.attributes = F)
[1] TRUE
> if(require(matrixStats))  
+   system.time(fold(MAT, f, aggr_FUN = colMedians))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.27    0.00    0.27 
> if(require(matrixStats))
+   system.time(fold(MAT, f, aggr_FUN = colSds))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.02    0.18
```

Unless, I'm really misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clean code for the for the matrix operation! It is indeed the fastest and cleanest. The only problem with your version is that I would like to me able to pass any function for the aggregate calculation so that median or something else could be used.

Based on the suggestions so far the fastest and cleanest so far has been added in EDIT2.

Comment: Changed to accomodate @JanStanstrup needs regarding the setting of both the aggregation and combination function. Just need to pass in col* function like the ones available in the matrixStats package. It's still fast because it avoids as much copying as possible, in addition to using the fast matrix functions.